# Including JSON header file

Tags: c++, json

I am new to JSON. I have to do parsing of JSON file in C++ in Windows. I don't know how to include rapidjson header file. I have downloaded the zip file from github but unable to include it in my project.
It is showing error.

[image]

Comment: Unless the library and the `rapidjson` directory is in the same directory as the `JsonCpp.cpp` source file, you need to edit your project settings to tell MSVC where the header files (or rather the `rapidjson` directory) is located.

Comment: I have put my project and rapidjson in same directory. But though it is not showing error but while compiling it is telling that no such directory exist.